# How do I troubleshoot "Port 8080 was already in use" with automated deployments with AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, travis-ci, aws-code-deploy

I am practicing Spring Boot automatic deployment using `Travis CI`, `AWS S3`, and `AWS CodeDeploy`. Currently, if I do `git push`, automatic deployment is in progress, but the following problem occurs.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

So, I used the following command to check the process using port 8080.

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:8080
```

The user resulted in `ec2-user`. If I kill `ec2-user` with a kill pid to use port 8080, the server cannot be used. How to solve it?

### [EDIT]

#### appspec.yml

```
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deploy.sh
      timeout: 60
      runas: ec2-user
```

#### deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORY=/home/ec2-user/app/travis
PROJECT_NAME=springboot-test

echo "> Copy Build File"

cp $REPOSITORY/zip/*.jar $REPOSITORY/

echo "> confirm current application pid"

CURRENT_PID=$(pgrep -fl $PROJECT_NAME | grep jar | awk '{print $1}')

echo "> pid: $CURRENT_PID"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_PID" ]; then
  echo "> No application"
else
  echo "> kill -15 $CURRENT_PID"
  kill -15 $CURRENT_PID
  sleep 5
fi

echo "> Deploy new application"

JAR_NAME=$(ls -tr $REPOSITORY/*.jar | tail -n 1)

echo "> JAR Name: $JAR_NAME"

echo "> Add +x in $JAR_NAME"

chmod +x $JAR_NAME

echo "> run $JAR_NAME"

nohup java -jar \
  -Dspring.config.location=/home/ec2-user/app/application.yml \
  -Dspring.profiles.active=real \
  $JAR_NAME > $REPOSITORY/nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add [ApplicationStop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server) hook into your `appspec.yml`. The hook is executed first, and you should define it so that it stops your web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thanks to @Marcin, I found out about the existence of ```ApplicationStop```. But if you look at my deploy script, it kills the server with ```kill -15```, is it necessary to add ```ApplicationStop```?? While I was adding, I have a question because I do not know how to configure the ```stop_deploy.sh``` file for ```ApplicationStop```.

Comment: @hanjiman Its not necessary. Have you confirmed your `kill -15` actually works? Maybe your system restarts your server automatically if you stop it this way?

Comment: To be honest, the ```kill -15``` code didn't work. Failed to catch ```CURRENT_PID```. So I'm trying to add ```ApplicationStop``` to hooks as you said, can you tell me what ```stop_deploy.sh``` to use for ```ApplicationStop```?

Comment: @hanjiman I would suggest making new question with details of you `appspec.yaml`. exact setup of your application and errors you get. It would be better than just keep editing and adding new issues to your original question.